# Puppeteer loading profile - only load extension & extension settings, not cookies, cache, or history

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer, chromium, webautomation

I am using puppeteer to scrape a website and I want the chromium browser to open with an extension enabled (with some settings already put in).
I am doing this by saving & loading the chromium profile so that those extension settings are applied.

Doing this by -  `pup.launch({headless: false, args: ['--user-data-dir=/profiles/'], ignoreDefaultArgs: ['--disable-extensions']})`

This works fine but the issue is that the website I don't want the website to use my cookies (as it prevents me from doing what I want to), also it won't load if I disable cookies entirely.

I found that it worked by manually going into chromium settings and clearing cookies, history, and cache after every session (but disabling them entirely did not work as the website doesn't let you load it then). But doing this manually is not possible when I am running this iteration hundreds of time.

TL;DR: I want to be able to load and save only extension & extension settings on chromium profile and not the cookies & other data.